# Git - nothing to commit , working tree clean even after modifying file

Tags: git, github, repository, push, commit

I'm trying to push the file RecordLinkage.ipynb to my remote repository but anytime I create it or modify it git doesn't react to it at all.
Using `git status` and `git commit -m "Commit message"` I get "On branch main, nothing to commit , working tree clean"

Whenever I modify the file I follow this procedure:

1. `git add .` or `git add --all` (Tried both)
2. check `git status` -> nothing to commit
3. I try committing anyways -> nothing to commit (as expected)

The upstream is set correctly, **main** is the branch I want to be on. The file RecordLinkage.ipynb isn't on there (not even on the other branch).

What's weird is that any other file is tracked by git. It seems that only new *.ipynb* files are ignored. This is my *.gitignore* file:

```
src/*
src/datasets_zip/*
!src/datasets_zip
!src/datasets_zip/*.zip

!final_dataset.csv

*.txt
*.pdf
```

This is my remote repository:

[image]

And this is my local repository:

[image]

I also reinitialised the local repository with the usual procedure.

Comment: Try to re-save the file. Seems like something is broken when saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked one of my partners to push another notebook, I pulled it and everything went smooth after that